# template function - no instance matching the argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I have a DLL which is performing a bigger job. For logging it sends its messages to a log-server via a callback function provided with the user data `pGlobal` on calling the dll functions (not shown). Inside there is a convenience function which is formating a string before sending it to the actual log function.

```
template <typename ...Args>
void logArgs(pData* pGlobal, char* format, Args&&...args)
{
    char buffer[2048];
    sprintf_s(buffer, format, forward<Args>(args)...);
    logfunc(pGlobal, string(buffer));
}
//...
logArgs(pGlobal, "Sequence done, %d frames processed", pGlobal->seqData.actualFrames);
```

The code worked well in the old build environment (an ancient VS2013), but when I switched to VS2022 I get the following error when building:

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "logArgs" matches the argument list 
argument types are: (trigGlobals *, const char [39], UINT)
```

I must admit I have no idea, what the problem is. I was playig around with the `char*` as the function os passing a `const char` but withoug success.

Comment: Literal strings are really *constant* arrays of characters. You *must* use `const char*` for pointers to them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thats it, thanks! Strange though that the ancient compiler was fine with it.

Comment: simpler example much clearer error message: https://godbolt.org/z/qnsv6xMfK

Comment: before C++11 it was allowed to point to a string literal with a `char*` (even though it was already const, and also via the pointer to non const you were not able to modify it).

Comment: Ancient C didn't have a `const` keyword, so a `char*` had to be used to point to strings, including string literals. C++ initially allowed this too, for compatibility .

Comment: @BoP Wow, that takes me back.